# HTML input element size of 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
  $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="0">
```

When the input renders, it should have 0 width, and when it has no text in it, it should have 0 width.

Instead it takes on default width. `size` attribute works correctly for all sizes greater than 0.

How can I get a 0 size attribute on an input elmeent to be rendered like 0 width by the browser?

Comment: That would be [in accordance with the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#size). The `size` attribute is not allowed to be zero. After all, how is someone going to click on an input element to start typing, if there is nothing to click on? That would make no sense.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am able to click 0-width contenteditables to type in them

Comment: Not without artificially increasing their content box you're not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I apologise, you're right. I'd been doing it with ones with borders. Thanks for pointing out the spec for the `size` attribute to me.

Answer (score 1):

in this case I would recommend you to use `style='width: 0ch'`. The length of the field will be the size of one char:

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
  $(this).css('width', $(this).val().length + 'ch');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style='width: 0ch'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS attribute selector to apply `width: 0px` to all input elements where the `size` attribute is `0`.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
})
```

```css
input[size="0"] {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="0">
```

Although you'd be better off setting its width to `0px` onload for syntactically valid HTML:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
}).width(0)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="0">
```

Comment: Except `size="0"` didn't suddenly stop being an illegal value, so let's not set that in the HTML, and let's not make an answer rely on setting an illegal value =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans True. I'll provide an alternative

Comment: The real answer, of course, is "don't hide text inputs. Make sure people can always click on them". A zero-width text input makes no sense whatsoever.